# Do I need stringlength if I already have regex as a data attribute for c# property

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have this below. It seems like the regex would be good enough but not sure?

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Routing is required")]
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 9, ErrorMessage = "Your routing number must be 9 digits")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{9}$", ErrorMessage = "Routing number must be 9 digits. 0-9")]
    public string Routing { get; set; }
```

Comment: I agree, it seems like the RegEx covers it.

Comment: That StringLength is not doing anything useful. If anything, it may complicate things if the user first enters "AAAAA" then "AAAAAAAA" (to put all 9 characters) and *then* 123456789. Just leave the RegEx there

Comment: What happened when you tried it?